# Unable to edit/replace string value with plus symbol "+" in text file via PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, replace, special-characters

I'm trying to update a group of XML based .config files.  There is a string in the file that contains a plus sign that I cannot replace with my script:

```
< SharedPassKey=123456789abcdefghi/JKLM+nopqrst= />
```

If I include the plus sign, the script does nothing.  Since all the configs vary I need to replace the text - cannot just go with new files.

The desired result is that the matching value in the file be replaced with the specified value, but the `+` symbol is not allowing this. Here is my PS script:

```
$DIRs = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\TEST" -Directory 
Get-ChildItem $DIRs -File -Recurse -Filter *.config | 
    ForEach { (Get-Content $_.FullName) | 
    ForEach { $_ -replace '< SharedPassKey=123456789abcdefghi/JKLM+nopqrst= />','< SharedPassKey=123456789abcdefghi/JKLM.nopqrst= />' } | 
    Set-Content $_.FullName }
```

As a test I replaced all the text up to the plus sign and it worked fine, but the plus sign and following were present at the end of the new text as I had left the "+nopqrst" out of the script.

Running on PSv3, FYI.

Comment: try a backslash character before the plus sign

Comment: `< foo=bar= />` is invalid XML. Does your data actually look like that? Otherwise working with an XML parser might be a more suitable approach.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - No my XML is normal, this was just a quick representation with all the info stripped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-3.0) operator uses a regular expression for the first postfix argument to define the search pattern.  In a regular expression, certain characters have a [special meaning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference).  `+` in particular is a so-called "quantifier" with the meaning "one or more times the preceding (sub)expression".  In order to replace literal special characters, you need to escape them.

Fortunately, there's a built-in [method for escaping strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx):

```
$_ -replace [RegEx]::Escape('< SharedPassKey=123456789abcdefghi/JKLM+nopqrst= />'),'< SharedPassKey=123456789abcdefghi/JKLM.nopqrst= />'
```

Comment: Beware, though, that `[regex]::Escape()` will escape all special characters in the given string. If you just want to replace one literal (sub)string with another you may want to consider using the `String.Replace()` method instead: `$_.Replace('foo', 'bar')`.

Comment: Both are very helpful!  @Ansgar, thanks for that tip, I've not used that method but will not shy away in the future.

Comment: @Bacon Bits solved this one for me! His adjustment to my script proved to be successful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have valid XML data and you want to modify the value of a node attribute in an XML file you may want to consider using a proper XML parser, like this:

```
$xmlfile = 'C:\path\to\your.config'

[xml]$xml = Get-Content $xmlfile
$attr = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//somenode/@SharedPassKey')
$attr.'#text' = $attr.'#text'.Replace('+', '.')

$xml.Save($xmlfile)
```

Make the [XPath expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471.aspx) for selecting the attribute as specific as it needs to be. That will allow you to replace a `+` with a `.` in just that attribute.

Comment: Hi Ansgar,  I've been doing it this with -replace for a long time, but finally a special character stopped me in my tracks.  

I am not familiar with the method you provided and it doesn't seem the example you left will cover a multiple files in the in the sub-directories.  I also don't know how to specify the string to be edited with this method. 

Obviously, I'm not expecting a lesson and I'm doing my own research/studying now, however, your input and previous comments are greatly appreciated.  If I can learn this method it may prove to be more efficient.

Comment: The code is just an example of how to replace an attribute value using an XML parser. It's not meant to be a turnkey solution. Also, with this approach you don't specify a single string. You have an XPath expression for selecting the attribute(s) whose value you want to change, and a replacement operation for the value.